# Build failed: org/apache/http/ssl/SSLInitializationException

Tags: gradle, debian

I get this exception every time I run gradle. No matter where I run gradle, it says build failed with `org/apache/http/ssl/SSLInitializationException` as reason.

I have no idea what is causing it, and why it happens, and it seems like gradle is completely unable to do anything at all.

```
$ gradle --version
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.13
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-09-04 20:51:16 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     <unknown>

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on October 7 2014
JVM:          1.8.0_101 (Oracle Corporation 25.101-b13)
OS:           Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 amd64
```

Anyone have any idea what is going on, and why this happens?

Long stacktrace:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
org/apache/http/ssl/SSLInitializationException

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/ssl/SSLInitializationException
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.DefaultSslContextFactory.<init>(DefaultSslContextFactory.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourcesPluginServiceRegistry$GlobalScopeServices.createSslContextFactory(HttpResourcesPluginServiceRegistry.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.invoke(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:426)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.access$1200(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:739)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:695)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:537)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:577)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.doGet(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:393)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:378)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ParentServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:949)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:894)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:894)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1120)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1117)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1074)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1062)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:398)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.doGet(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:390)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:378)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ParentServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:949)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:894)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:894)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1120)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1117)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1074)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1062)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.bind(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.prepare(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:582)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:595)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$OwnServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:486)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:894)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1120)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1117)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1074)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1062)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.bind(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.prepare(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:582)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:595)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$OwnServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:486)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:894)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1120)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1117)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1074)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1062)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.bind(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.prepare(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:582)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:595)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$OwnServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:486)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:894)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1120)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1117)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1074)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1062)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.bind(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.prepare(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:582)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:595)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$OwnServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:486)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:894)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1120)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1117)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1074)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1062)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:398)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.doGet(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:390)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:374)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.createScriptObjectConfigurerFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:227)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.invoke(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:426)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.access$1200(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:739)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:695)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:537)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:577)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:705)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:694)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:537)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:577)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.doGet(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:393)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:374)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.doNewInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:241)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:214)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:207)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 116 more
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have exactly the same issue.